# Removing mould from baby clothing

Tags: toddler, hygiene, cleaning

The collar and cuff of my daughter's Baby Bjorn bib have become quite mouldy. Probably because we didn't wash them soon enough, or put them in a bag whilst still damp when we were out of the house.

[image: Baby Bjorn bib collar and cuff]

There are plenty of products which can kill/remove mould or mildew, but I think they're pretty harsh and poisonous and she's likely to chew these or eat food off them. I don't really want to put these items on a really hot wash (over 40 deg C), as it might ruin them.

Does anyone have any ideas for cleaning this mould off in a way that is safe for a baby/toddler?

Comment: I believe sunlight (UV) should help kill mould, but I don't have enough experience to state that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Soak in a mix of vinegar and water. This will kill the mould, and it is relatively safe. Then wash.

Bleach would be no good. Apart from being more harmful if any stays in the clothes, it only whitens the mould, rather than killing it.

[This is based on information I read online for removing mould from walls.]

Comment: Bleach or detergent on a plastic surface should be good enough to remove mould. It's not really the same as for walls where the texture will be more absorbent.

Comment: In this case it appears that vinegar and water does not work, even with some scrubbing.

Answer (score 1):

Living in Asia this is something I often have to deal with. What I find always works for me is to either:

- Soak the clothes in hot (close to boiling) water for 30 minute, then wash, or
- Wash on hot (as hot as possible)

I have always been able to get every trace of it out of my child's clothes, including all of the smell. Because of the climate (and other issues) in this part of the world, I often have to repeat this process once every year or two.

Comment: As stated, I don't want to put them on a really hot wash as it will damage the (plasticky) clothing. The elastic in one cuff has already gone loose due, I think, to being left on a hot radiator.